# how to include serial number to query result with spring jpa native query?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have tried this query:

`SELECT @rownumber:=@rownumber+1 as rownumber, column From Table, (SELECT @rownumber:=0) D`

in my workbench and it works but it does work in spring data jpa. I get this error instead:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [0, @rownumber]`

I have tried switching the postion of the colon like this `@rownumber=:@rownumber+1` and `@rownumber=:0`

What could be the problem with the query? Is there a way to correct it or is there proven way to include serial number in my query result?

Comment: How do you call the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape the `:` char and use `\\:`

```
SELECT @rownumber\\:=@rownumber+1 as rownumber, column 
From Table, (SELECT @rownumber\\:=0) D
```